# Find Pivot Data grouped by management hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

There are two tables : 
1 . Applications :

```
 id | cost | user_id (FK)
 34756 | 1186 | 1
 37638 | 25  | 2
 37636 | 80  |  3
 37636 | 85  |  4
 37636 | 50  |  5
 37636 | 5  |   5
 37636 | 8  |   6
 37636 | 10  |  7
```

2. Users table :

```
 id | mgr_id
 1 | null --- top
 2  | 1   --- top-1
 3  | 1   --- top-1
 4  | 2   --- top-2
 5  | 2   --- top-2
 6  | 3   --- top-2
 7  | 3   --- top-2
```

Expected output : Tow columns one with the top-1 hierarchy users and the other column having the sum of application cost

```
   id | cost
   2   | 165
   3   | 98
```

My question is to find out the sum of applications cost for all users who report to top-1 hierarchy grouped by top-1 hierarchy users. Can this be done by a single query?

Comment: provide your expected output.

Comment: I just added few lines of table and output ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this is a recursive CTE to generate the managers.

However, I find this question challenging.  If you wanted everyone *strictly* below the second level managers, then you can use a recursive CTE is generate the managers and just choose the second-level ones.

But, you also want to add back in the values for those managers.  That requires one extra step, I think.

The following does what you want:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select u.id,'{}'::int[] as mgrs, 1 as lev
      from users u
      where mgr_id is null
      union all
      select u.id, (mgrs || array[u.mgr_id]), lev + 1
      from cte join
           users u
           on u.mgr_id = cte.id
     )
select cte.mgrs[2], sum(t.cost) + coalesce(tm.cost, 0)
from cte join
     t
     on t.user_id = cte.id left join
     (select t.user_id, sum(cost) as cost
      from t
      group by t.user_id
     ) tm
     on cte.mgrs[2] = tm.user_id
where cardinality(mgrs) >= 2
group by mgrs[2], tm.cost;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=26b427a556765eccc1d861b3689c0f21) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is a great answer but how do I bring in the user name in the output . I am sorry , I missed in the question , but there is a column "name" in the users table.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand . . . You would just join to whatever table has the user name or include it in the recursive CTE.  Either method.

Comment: My users table has the username. I tried adding in cte but output is not matching

Comment: @AbhishekAnand . . . Perhaps you want to ask a new question.  This one has been answered.